How to get specific amount of data from each node with callBack Implementation and also with pagination in Firebase?
I am developing an Android application for kids, I am using Firebase real-time database as my db to store values, when I retrieve values from Firebase, I want to retrieve values when it's ready, for that I am using callBacks, also I want to retrieve 10 data from each subnode with pagination, I have tried this by putting it into a loop. it is not working. here I am expecting somehelp to achieve this.
here is my Firebase structure:

this is the code I have tried
    private void readAllCategoryData(FirebaseAllCategoryDataCallBack firebaseAllCategoryDataCallBack) {
        Map<String,List<OneModel>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
            int finalI = i;
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    List<OneModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                        String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                        ModelData modelData = dataSnapshot.getValue(ModelData.class);
                        OneModel model = new OneModel(key,modelData);
                        modelList.add(model);
                    }
                    map.put(array.get(finalI), modelList);
                    testModelMap = map;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loop "+finalI+","+map, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // displays the data but not in a sequential order
                    Log.i("LOOP"+finalI,""+map); //Logged the data but not in a sequential order
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            };
            categoryReference.child(array.get(i)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
            
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "All"+testModelMap, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //  Map is empty
        Log.i("OUTSIDE LOOP",""+map); // No Values in the logged map
        Log.i("OUTSIDE LOOP1",""+testModel); // No Values in the logged map
        firebaseAllCategoryDataCallBack.onAllCategoryDataCallBack(map);
    }

what I want to do is, retrieve 10 data from each node for the first time and send it to callback as a map, and do the pagination after.
Here are the logs recorded with timestamps

2024-04-15 22:52:56.772  8222-8222  OUTSIDE LOOP   I  {}
2024-04-15 22:52:56.772  8222-8222  OUTSIDE LOOP1  I  {}
2024-04-15 22:53:00.500  8222-8222  LOOP3          I  {Some Values}
2024-04-15 22:53:00.596  8222-8222  LOOP4          I  {Some more Values than LOOP3}
2024-04-15 22:53:00.657  8222-8222  LOOP0          I  {Some more Values than LOOP4}
2024-04-15 22:53:00.676  8222-8222  LOOP2          I  {Some more Values than LOOP0}
2024-04-15 22:53:00.693  8222-8222  LOOP5          I  {Some more Values than LOOP2}
2024-04-15 22:53:00.768  8222-8222  LOOP1          I  {Some more Values than LOOP5/FullMap I want}


I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

In addition to what Alex said, stop ignoring errors and implement onCancelled. At its minimum that should be public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }.

Hi @AlexMamo , I have updated my question with logs, I don't have any errors, but it doesn't run sequentially, it gives map values in a loop, but when i access from it outside the loop it is empty

Hi @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for commenting, I will do as you said,  can you check on what I have updated? It's confusing

This looks like a problem with asynchronous data loading.
All data from Firebase (and most modern cloud APIs) is loaded asynchronously, as it will take some time to get it.
While the data is being loaded, your main code continues to run - which is why your OUTSIDE LOOP logs show no data.
Then when the data has been loaded, your onDataChange callback is invoked with that data.
This means that any code that needs access to the data from the database has to be inside onDataChange, be called from there, or be otherwise synchronized.

I linked a few questions that show how to do that. If you have multiple data loads that all need to be completed before you further process any of the data, you can do something like keep a counter to track how many callbacks have completed - and then only execute the final code once you've handled all loading.

Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen for making that clear, That was helpful, thanks!
